# Wormlike, worm-like or worm like?

Tags: adjective-phrases

How does one write that something is like something else using "like" as a suffix?

Possibilities that come to my mind are:

- X-like
- Xlike
- X like

Which of these forms are most common?

X could be a variety of things, anything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer varies from word to word. A search of "like as suffix" will provide some word lists. Some are compound words such as seamanlike and some are hyphenated such as target-like.

One of the lists: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-like

EDIT:

Generally speaking, only use the compound word when it is officially part of the language. If it's in the dictionary, you can use it. If it's not in the dictionary, it's not a "real word" and you should not use it. You should always be able to use the -like suffix with a hyphen.

As words come into more general usage as a compound word (such as seamanlike), they become part of the language. That's really the only distinction that I'm aware of. If someone has placed that compound word in the dictionary, use it that way. If not, use the hyphenated form.

SECOND EDIT:

Placing a space changes the meaning. "Like" becomes a verb. "Seamen like fish" uses "like" as a verb.

Comment: Is there any rule/pattern for when to use the compound and when to use a hyphen? What about using a space in between; is that also possible?

Comment: @Trilarion - edited response for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You say the "-like" with a hyphen should always work, but in the linked word list like 99% of the words are compounds. There was another variant in the question with a space in between. I wonder if that is also possible.

Comment: @Trilarion No - edited the response again for you :)

Comment: Thanks. That answers all my questions and will be helpful not only for me but hopefully also for all future visitors.